# website build works differently than a website preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just coded a website. To preview the website, I used `npm start`. This worked well and I was able to see animations on both chrome and safari. However after building the website using `npm run build` and then `serve -s build`, the website build doesn't show animations on chrome but does show animations on safari.

For reference, this is what my CSS style sheet looks like.

```
@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}

#projectHead {
  -webkit-animation-name: appear 4s;
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

All the properties are displayed but the animations. To give a visual estimate, appear should smoothly transition in 4s. This happens for the time before the build but while viewing the build, my animations on chrome look like a staggered discrete animation in which I get 0% opacity at 1s and 100% opacity at 4s and no transition in between.

Someone please help! I have been trying to debug since morning.

Comment: Have you tried to using Chrome Dev Tool to inspect the element on the production build vs on the dev build? The CSS styles could be different due to your build tool configuration.

Comment: Clear the cache.  The browser cache

Comment: `npm start` will start the server in Development mode and `npm run build` will start the server in production mode. First stop the development server then try to run this command: `npm run build` to start the production server.